# add button to datatable row dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have a problem when adding a custom bit of HTML to a datatable cell on loading.

on clicking the tab to open the page, I call on a ajax function to fetch the data.

> ```
> // CLICK on the tab to open the User Manager -> Load all records into DataTable
>     $("#admin_details").click(function(){
>         // Send through the function to perform in the $_GET variable
>         $.ajax({
>             url: './inc/AdminScripts.php?argument=loadAllRecords'
>         })
>             .done(function(html) {
>                 var t = $('#users_table').DataTable();
>                 t.clear();
>                 var obj = eval(html);
>
>                 // ADD acquired data items to the DataTable
>                 $.each(obj, function(key,value) {
>                     t.row.add( [
>                         value.edit,
>                         value.name,
>                         value.surname,
>                         value.username,
>                         value.email,
>                         value.language,
>                         value.securityQuestion,
>                         value.securityAnswer,
>                         value.administrator,
>                         value.status,
>                         value.id
>                     ] ).draw();
>                 });
>                 addBellsWhistles();
>             })
>     });
> ```

This bit works fine and I get all the data I require. The problem now is that for the `EDIT` column I want to add a `ICON BUTTON` to click on to edit the record. I do so using a function `addBellsWhistles` like this

> ```
>     function addBellsWhistles(){
>         $('#users_table tr').children("td:nth-child(1)").append("<div class='col1d'><button class='editBut'><img src='img/property32.png'></button></div>");
>     }
> ```

okay, this also work almost perfectly except for one thing. The data table only shows 10 records per page, so when I go to the 2nd or nth page the piece of custom added HTML is not visable.

I have tried the following on click of the paginate button (well quite a few things including the the `class` of the button, `id` of the button, the `a tag` of the button) but nothing works.

Im also using `deligation` in this case because of dynamically created data

e.g.

> ```
>     $( ".dataTables_paginate a" ).on( 'click', '.paginate_button', function () {
>         console.log('paging');
>         $(".confirmUploadError .confirm_text").html("Loading records. Please wait.");
>         $(".confirmUploadError").fadeIn(250).delay(300).fadeOut(650);
>         addBellsWhistles();
>     });
> ```

its not writing to console, its not calling the message pop-up and it is especially not calling my function (and I just named them separately for dramatic effect).

Anyone out there have a idea for me please?

PS here is the datatable paginate container as created by datatables

> ```
>        <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="users_table_paginate">
>            <a class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="users_table" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" id="users_table_previous">Previous</a>
>                <span>
>                    <a class="paginate_button current" aria-controls="users_table" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a>
>                    <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="users_table" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a>
>                </span>
>            <a class="paginate_button next" aria-controls="users_table" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0" id="users_table_next">Next</a>
>        </div>
> ```

Comment: I believe that columns.render() [link](http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) provides the functionality you require.

Comment: @MarcoBorchert -> I believe you are right. one thing i did not expect though is that it now added a icon in cell (0,0) for each cell in the table. e.g. 110 ICONSand in all column 0 cell after that... :%  so thanks it worked, just need some work on it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Call the `fnCreatedRow` function, which fires after every row is created (callback). 
Call your method from there to do what is needed. In this case:

> ```
>    $('#users_table').dataTable( {
>        "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
>            $('td:eq(0)', nRow).append("<div class='col1d'><button class='editBut'><img >src='img/property32.png'></button></div>");
>        },
>    });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
This Code is working for me here i am adding button to get next set records or search record from server.  



ObjTableId.button().add(3, {
                action: function () {
                   // your code goes here !
                },
                text: 'Button text',
                className: "css_class_name",
                attr: {
                    title: 'title',
                    id: 'btnId'
                }
            });
```